# How to disable IOS In-App Purchase capability in Codenameone

Tags: ios, codenameone

we are using generic provisioning profiles for development purposes. But when using them in Codenameone IOS Debug builds, I get the following error.

```
error: Provisioning profile "X" doesn't support the In-App Purchase capability. (in target 'Main' from project 'Main')
error: Provisioning profile "X" doesn't match the entitlements file's values for the application-identifier and keychain-access-groups entitlements. (in target 'Main' from project 'Main')
```

I have checked hints and could not found a way to turn off In-App Purchase capability (which seems to be enabled by default for all builds). Is there a way to disable it. Thank you.

Best regards,
CS

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't see the full log it's hard to tell but try disabling our own validation to see if it helps with the build hint: `ios.validateProvisioningProfile=false`.

Why can't you just turn on the in app purchase capability in the profile?

I looked through the build code but couldn't see any specific mention of that requirement so it might be a hidden dependency that we didn't notice because our wizard turns it on automatically for generated provisioning.

I'm more concerned about the second error. What did you define for app id?

You need to use the `*` identifier for an all-apps debug provisioning.

Comment: The second error was solved by fixing app id in the "release section" of the IOS Signing codenameone settings (debug section does not have one). I did not know this matters since I was using only debug. The first error remains. Unfortunately one cannot create a generic profile (this means using wildcards for identifiers) and enable IOS App Purchase. It is disabled by default by the apple system. It is enabled by default for explicit identifiers. In both cases this setting cannot be changed.

Comment: I'll need to look into that. This used to be possible but since the certificate wizard works so well I stopped using this feature a while back. AFAIK it should be possible to build without this. Just to verify, you aren't implementing the purchase callback interface or anything like that, right?

Comment: No, nothing like that. It is a really simple app.

Comment: Can you send the error log to the chat on the website. We'll have a look and see if there's something we're missing there.